# SQL jobs db mail do not mail if query returns null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My script that is run is below.

```
use msdb
go
exec sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'New Pending',
@recipients ='hepl@example.com',
@subject = 'New Pending Data',
@query = 'use database exec PendingData2'
```

I think i need to add a step before this one that runs PendingData2 and if it returns a null or no data that it ends the task and dose not run the step above.

This was my solution.

```
DECLARE @return_value1 int
EXEC @return_value1 = [database].[dbo].[PendingData2] 

if (@return_value1 > 0)
BEGIN
use msdb
exec sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'New Pending',
@recipients ='help@example.com',
@subject = 'New Pending Data',
@query = 'use database exec PendingData2'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
Print 'nothing'
END
```

I also had to add the following code to my PendingData2 stored procedure.

```
declare @parameters nchar(100)
declare @sql nchar(100)
declare @return_value1 Int
set @return_value1 = (select Sum(@a + @b + @c + @d + @e + @f + @g + @h + @i + @j + @k + @l + @m + @n + @o + @p + @q + @r + @t + @u + @v + @w + @x + @y) )
set @sql = 'select @return_value1'
set @parameters = '@return_value1 int OUTPUT'
exec sp_executesql @sql, @parameters, @return_value1 = @return_value1 OUTPUT
return @return_value1
```

The @a and so on are declared as Int and its based on a count of records in a table.

Comment: try using `IF EXISTS`

Comment: Ok in this code or in a different step use the IF EXISTS with use database exec PendingData2?

Comment: I would just use it in the same step.